# CodeIgniter with PostgreSQL and PgBouncer in Transaction mode

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Previously we used PostgreSQL 9 with PgBouncer in session mode, and with that was able to easily create a new record and get the last ID with `db->insert_id('table', 'pk_column')`.

But the use of the Session mode of PgBouncer proved to be extremely problematic for us, with several operations per second, the Pool easily reached the capacity of connections, so we switched to PostgreSQL 12 with PgBouncer in Transaction mode.

One problem that has begun to occur with this mode is that using operations that require being in the same session does not work, not allowing to use `CURRVAL`, which is used by `insert_id()`,

Example of INSERT created by CodeIgniter 3:

```
INSERT INTO "table" ("column") VALUES ('ABC');
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('table', 'tableid') AS seq;
SELECT CURRVAL('public.table_tableid_seq') AS ins_id;
```

This code will trigger the error:

```
currval has not yet been defined this session
```

Is there any configuration that must be done in CodeIgniter to work with PgBouncer in transaction mode?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all these statements run in a single database transaction, then there should be no problem.

Comment: From what I read in the CodeIgniter [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html), it would be something like that, correct?

`$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->insert();
$this->db->insert_id();
$this->db->trans_complete();`

Comment: @tom did you work out with this solution?

Comment: @myalcin81 My only option was to create a function in the helper that does an INSERT and concatenates a return id.
In this link there is an example of what I did.
Is she pretty to look at? No, but it works.

https://gist.github.com/El-Tommy/2a31dd0611279ee4aeabf2719414cbe6

Comment: ty @Tom I did same also I couldnt figure out real root cause